# Why can my child object not access its parent's function?

Tags: c++

Even if I try the other getter functions which are defined in cpp files my compiler does not let me do so.
If I try boar.getEnemyName(); it tells me expression must have class type.

```
class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy(std::string enemyName, int enemyHealth, int enemyAttack, int enemyDefense, int enemyMoney)
    {
        name = enemyName;
        health = enemyHealth;
        attackValue = attackValue;
        defenseValue = enemyDefense;
        moneyDrop = enemyMoney;
    }

    std::string getEnemyName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    int getEnemyHealth();
    int getEnemyHealth();
    int getEnemyMoney();
    int getEnemyAttack();
    int getEnemyDefense();

private:
    std::string name = "";
    int health = 0;
    int moneyDrop = 0;
    int attackValue = 0;
    int defenseValue = 0;

    std::string itemDrop;

};

class Boar : public Enemy
{
public:

private:
};

int main()
{
    initializePlayerForestDistance();
    srand(time(0));
    bool gameIsRunning = true;
    //while (gameIsRunning == true)
    {
    //  gameLoop();
    }
    Boar boar(std::string name = "Boar", int health = 20, int attack = 1, int defense = 1, int money = 10);
    return 0;
    boar.getEnemyName(); // this part does not work
    boar.getEnemyHealth(); // also this would not work
}
```

In my boar class I'd rather not put in `std::string getEnemyName() { return name; }` as it's just copy and pasting code. Or putting `std::string getEnemyName() { Enemy::getEnemyName() }` in my boar class.

Comment: If this is your code verbatim, the Boar class (and the Enemy) are both defined after main. You should put them before it.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR Nah it's not. Fixed though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
Boar boar(std::string name = "Boar", int health = 20, int attack = 1, int defense = 1, int money = 10);
```

is not constructing a `Boar`, it's actually a declaration of a function named `boar` that returns a `Boar`, and takes 5 default arguments.

This explains the error `expression must have class type`, when you do `boar.getEnemyName();`, because you are trying to call a method on a function type, which is not possible.

If you want to call the constructor, you need to do:

```
Boar boar("Boar", 20, 1, 1, 10);
```

And to use this constructor taking 5 arguments (assuming you want the one from the base class `Enemy`), you need to bring that into `Boar` with a `using` declaration, like this:

```
class Boar : public Enemy
{
  public:
    using Enemy::Enemy;
};
```